# Drawing an object to a Form from outside

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm a newbie at C# and I tried to make a separate *DBService* class, and I wanted to draw my DataGridView from this class. 
But it doesn't appear.

```
 public static void initializeDataDisplay()
    {
        try
        {
            string selectAll = @"SELECT * FROM Products;";
            MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectAll, DBService.conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
            DataGridView dgvAdmin = new DataGridView();
            dgvAdmin.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            dgvAdmin.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(29, 12);
            dgvAdmin.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(552, 245);
            dgvAdmin.TabIndex = 0;
            dgvAdmin.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

The connection works, and everything worked before i wanted to separate the Database services. I don't get any exceptions.

Comment: dgvAdmin doesn't belong to your form.  You created a new grid and then it just goes out of scope.  Maybe try passing the grid reference instead: `initializeDataDisplay(DataGridView dgvAdmin)`.

Comment: also have you stepped through the code to see in the debugger when using the `QuickWatch` when clicking on the little magnifying glass, does ds.Tables[0] display any populated data..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new control it will not be displayed until it has been added to a displayed Form or other container that is showing inside a Form.

I would recommend that you add a DataGridView instance to your application using the Form designer. Then when you call your initializeDataDisplay routine you pass in a reference to this designer generated instance and update inside the routine.